# Scala forward or delegate methods to encapsulated object

Tags: scala, delegates, forward-declaration, delegation

Is there any possibility to implicitly forward some of class methods to encapsulated object?

```
case class Entity(id: Int, name: String,) {
  private lazy val lastScan = new LastScan

  def getLastScanDate    = lastScan.getLastScanDate
  def updateLastScanDate = lastScan.updateLastScanDate
}
```

I want to avoid creating `def updateLastScanDate = lastScan.updateLastScanDate` just to forward methods to wrapped object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the plain language this is not possible. There used to be a compiler plugin by Kevin Wright to achieve this automatic delegation.

He seems to be working on an [Autorproxy "Rebooted"](https://github.com/thecoda/autoproxy) version now that is macro based, making it straight forward to include in your project. I'm pasting here an example from its test sources:

```
trait Bippy {
  def bippy(i : Int): String
}

object SimpleBippy extends Bippy {
  def bippy(i: Int) = i.toString
}

@delegating class RawParamWrapper(@proxy pivot: Bippy)
val wrapper = new RawParamWrapper(SimpleBippy)
assert(wrapper.bippy(42) == "42")
```