# Way to enhance a class with function delegation

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I have the following classes in Scala:

```
class A {
    def doSomething() = ???

    def doOtherThing() = ???
}

class B {
    val a: A

    // need to enhance the class with both two functions doSomething() and doOtherThing() that delegates to A
    // def doSomething() = a.toDomething()
    // def doOtherThing() = a.doOtherThing()
}
```

I need a way to enhance at compile time class B with the same function signatures as A that simply delegate to A when invoked on B.

Is there a nice way to do this in Scala?

Thank you.

Comment: Related, but very old and open-ended thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473309/proxies-delegates-in-scala

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27035808/scala-forward-or-delegate-methods-to-encapsulated-object

Answer (score 7):

In Dotty (and in future Scala 3), it's [now available](https://dotty.epfl.ch/blog/2019/04/15/14th-dotty-milestone-release.html#export-as-a-dual-of-import) simply as

```
class B {
    val a: A

    export a
}
```

Or `export a.{doSomething, doOtherThing}`.

For Scala 2, there is unfortunately no built-in solution. As Tim says, you can make one, but you need to decide how much effort you are willing to spend and what exactly to support.

Comment: what happens if two exports have similar method signatures?

Comment: @Dragonborn Maybe I don't understand what you mean (can you give an example?), but nothing special.

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid repeating the function signatures by making an alias for each function:

```
val doSomething = a.doSomething _
val doOtherthing = a.doOtherThing _
```

However these are now function values rather than methods, which may or may not be relevant depending on usage.

It might be possible to use a `trait` or a macro-based solution, but that depends on the details of why delegation is being used.

Comment: You can make them methods about as easily as values ... `def doSomething = a.doSomething` etc.

Answer (score 4):

Implicit conversion could be used for delegation like so

```
object Hello extends App {
  class A {
    def doSomething() = "A.doSomething"
    def doOtherThing() = "A.doOtherThing"
  }

  class B {
    val a: A = new A
  }

  implicit def delegateToA(b: B): A = b.a
  val b = new B
  b.doSomething() // A.doSomething
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is this macro [delegate-macro](https://github.com/cmhteixeira/delegate-macro) which might just be what you are looking for.  Its objective is to automatically implement the delegate/proxy pattern, so in your example your class `B` must extend class `A`.

It is cross compiled against `2.11`, `2.12`, and `2.13`. For `2.11` and `2.12` you have to use the macro paradise compile plugin to make it work. For `2.13`, you need to use flag `-Ymacro-annotations` instead.

Use it like this:

```scala
trait Connection {
  def method1(a: String): String
  def method2(a: String): String
  // 96 other abstract methods
  def method100(a: String): String
}

@Delegate
class MyConnection(delegatee: Connection) extends Connection {
  def method10(a: String): String = "Only method I want to implement manually"
}

// The source code above would be equivalent, after the macro expansion, to the code below
class MyConnection(delegatee: Connection) extends Connection {
  def method1(a: String): String = delegatee.method1(a)
  def method2(a: String): String = delegatee.method2(a)
  def method10(a: String): String = "Only method I need to implement manually"
  // 96 other methods that are proxied to the dependency delegatee
  def method100(a: String): String = delegatee.method100(a)
}
```

It should work in most scenarios, including when type parameters and multiple argument lists are involved.

Disclaimer: I am the creator of the macro.