# Generate functions at macros expansion time

Tags: scala, macros, metaprogramming, implicit, dotty

I would like to generate functions for a class accepting 1 type parameter

```
case class C[T] (t: T)
```

depending on the `T` type parameter.

The functions I would like to generate are derived by the functions available on `T`.

What I would like exactly, is to make all the functions available for `T`, also available for `C`.

As an example for `C[Int]`, I would like to be able to call on `C` any function available on `Int` and dispatch the function call to the `Int` contained in `C`.

```
val c1 = new C(1)
assert(c1 + 1 == 2)
```

How can I achieve this by using Scala 2 or dotty macros?
Or, can this be achieved in another way?

Comment: Possibly similar question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55826206/way-to-enhance-a-class-with-function-delegation/

Comment: @MarioGalic in that question a class is monomorhic, here it's polymorhic, this makes a difference. `export` seems not to work now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is easily achievable with [implicit conversions](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/implicit-conversions.html), so you don't really need macros:

```
case class C[T] (t: T)

object C { //we define implicit conversion in companion object
  implicit def conversion[T](c: C[T]): T = c.t
}

import scala.language.implicitConversions
import C._

val c1 = C(1)
assert(c1 + 1 == 2) //ok

val c2 = C(false)
assert(!c2 && true) //ok
```

Using **implicit conversions** means, that whenever compiler would notice, that types don't match, it would try to *implicitly* convert value applying *implicit function*.

Comment: thanks, this is definitely a right answer to my question
I would really appreciate you giving a try at a similar but more complex one I just posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56916413/generate-functions-based-on-type-parameter