# Generate functions based on type parameter

Tags: scala, macros, metaprogramming, implicit, dotty

I would like to generate functions for a class accepting 1 type parameter, which wraps a by name value.

```
class C[T](_t: => T) {
    def t: T = _t
}
```

The functions I would like to generate are derived by the functions available on `T`.

What I would like exactly, is to get all the functions available for `T`, change their **contract** and **implementation** in a programmatic way, and make them available for `C`.

- By changing their contract, I mean changing their signature so they return `C[R]`, where `R` stands for the return type of the original function.
- By changing their implementation, I mean wrapping the result inside `C` before returning it.

eg.

```
def +(that: Int): Int =
    this + that
```

would become available on `C[Int]` as

```
def +(that: Int): C[Int] =
    C(this.t + that)
```

This would be done in order to remove the boilerplate of having to wrap inside `C` a computation in order to keep it non-evaluated.

eg.

```
val c1 = new C(1)

val c2: C[Int] = C(c1.t + 1)
c2.t == 2
```

would be able to be expressed also as

```
val c2: C[Int] = c1 + 1
c2.t == 2
```

How can I achieve this by using Scala 2 or dotty macros? Or, can this be achieved in another way?

Answer (score 3):

Try to add one more implicit conversion additionally to advised by @KrzysztofAtłasik in your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56915573/5249621).

```
implicit def conversion[T](c: C[T]): T = c.t
implicit def conversion1[T](t: => T): C[T] = new C(t)
```

Or make class implicit

```
implicit class C[T](_t: => T) {
  def t: T = _t
}
```

Regarding macros, since you want to add definitions you would need [macro annotations](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html) rather than [def macros](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html). Dotty doesn't have macro annotations, it has only [inline macros](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/metaprogramming/toc.html) like Scala 2 def macros.

And macro annotations don't help either. When you define class `C[T]` it's not known what `T` is (this will be known only at call site), so it's not known what methods to add.

Dotty has implicit conversions too

```
given [T] as Conversion[T, C[T]] = new C(_)
given [T] as Conversion[C[T], T] = _.t
```

(currently it's `given`, formerly it was `implicit`, then `implied`, then `delegate`, currently in 0.17 `given`, this can change again).

It seems `Conversion[(=> T), C[T]]` is not allowed.

Comment: by using adding by name to the parameter of conversion1, it actually achieves lazyness
so conversion1 would become
implicit def conversion1[T](t: => T): C[T] = new C(t)

Comment: although, by using this approach, in order to preserve lazyness, the type of the computation needs to be explicitly set to C[T], otherwise T would be chosen and t evaluated